# Decode an Encrypted PHP File Assistance

Tags: php, decode, encryption

I have a file that I'm trying to decode but I'm not sure the best way to go about doing it.  I've tried putting it through a few online tools but haven't had much luck...the code looks like this:

```
<?php

$zAkSoSavjFOn='jumbledcodeinhere';

$THkNltHSOjsXfQLzr=';))))aBSwinFbFxNm$(ireegf(rqbprq_46rfno(rgnysavmt(ynir';

$DzbOntpeGhMcan=strrev($THkNltHSOjsXfQLzr);

$WnJYuMUwKmRxBh=str_rot13($DzbOntpeGhMcan);

eval($WnJYuMUwKmRxBh);

?>
```

In all my playing I managed to extract the following with a php script:

`eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(strrev($zAkSoSavjFOn))));`

Could someone point me in the right direction on going about this process? Any help would be appreciated.  :)

Comment: I am not sure this is actually encrypted - it looks more to be intentionally obfuscated to protect copyright/intellectual property rights. If you do not have access to the actual source then it is likely you are breaking the law by trying to decode this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "jumbled code" is gzipped, base64-encoded, reversed PHP code that is almost certainly malicious.

Replace `eval` with `echo` and see what it gives you, that's what the code that is trying to run is.

Comment: Replacing `eval` with `echo` returns the `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(strrev($zAkSoSavjFOn))));` code.

Comment: Ah, I meant the `eval` in that. Try this: `echo gzinflate(base64_decode(strrev($zAkSoSavjFOn)));`

Comment: Ok, I understand.  When I do that it returns the following, almost similar to the first block...

      `$dXWzuSHlsBFgCJhKbBgV='morejumbledcode';
    $PUjTLmBUZDuFRJ=';))))ItOoXuWPtSOfyUFhmJKq$(ireegf(rqbprq_46rfno(rgnysavmt(ynir';
    $FYYfZGltrAQcNREfSr=strrev($PUjTLmBUZDuFRJ);
    $_JmCKTmVJADRViXHTZE=str_rot13($FYYfZGltrAQcNREfSr);
    eval($_JmCKTmVJADRViXHTZE);`

Comment: Whoever wrote this code is going to great lengths to hide it. Just keep doing the same, replacing `eval` with `echo` until you get something that doesn't look the same.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting it finally led me to code that was legible but it's all about opening/closing curl.  the very last line looks like this:


`$_SESSION['awcvagcontent'] = $content; } else { $content = $_SESSION['awcvagcontent'];} } eval( ' ?>' . base64_decode( $content ) . '`


In my editor it's telling me there's an error on that last line of php and if i try to echo the eval found on the last line I just get a "unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE" error.

It seems odd to me that curl options were hidden... or maybe I'm still missing other parts of the code?