# php files encrypted need help decrypting them

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, cakephp, encryption

I have got a new client who has a website developed on php.

I don't know which framework was used or anything nor the client knows as he got it developed from some one else.

Now when I started looking in to the code, I saw all php files were encrypted.

Now even the client does not know which encryption method was used to encrypt the php files.

Point is I never used encryption methodology to encrypt any php files and hence this is quite new to me as I saw this for the first time.

Here is the sample code from one of the php files. I would greatly appreciate it if any one can help me through finding a method to decrypt the code so that I can start working on the project.

```
<?php ${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x62\x6b\x71\x74g\x66\x65vt"]="\x41\x44M\x49N\x49\x53T\x52A\x54OR";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["y\x70\x69ae\x6c\x62\x74l\x69w"]="\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x49\x6e\x4c\x69\x73\x74";${"GLO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x6ekev\x70\x77\x62\x68\x79\x7a"]="i\x6d\x61g\x65L\x69s\x74";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118531/decode-an-encrypted-php-file-assistance

Comment: They may be encoded by software intended to make them runnable but unreadable, in order to protect the intellectual property within. Can your client approach the original developer and get the raw source code?

Comment: @halfer I did ask the client to speak to the previous developer but he said some prob wid d dev etc etc .... so I need to figure it out ...

Comment: Alright, well it looks like you have an answer. Incidentally, please avoid text-speak here if possible - it makes it harder to read for people whose first language is not English. Questions _containing_ text-speak are frequently down-voted too.

Comment: Incidentally, since Dave points out that this decoding is easily reversible, my initial view that it was professionally obfuscated (e.g. with IonCube PHP Encoder) appears to be wrong. This could be an attempt to do the same on the cheap - it's difficult to say what the intention was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Decoded](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=840d767ff3e2a6fcf4666e2a29fea67e) looks like:

```
<?php

${"GLOBALS"}["bkqtgfevt"]   = "ADMINISTRATOR";
${"GLOBALS"}["ypiaelbtliw"] = "firstInList";
${"GLOBALS"}["nkevpwbhyz"]  = "imageList";
${"GLOBALS"}
```

Looks like part of a template. You can use [this site](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) to decode the rest of the script.

Comment: wow finally some decrypting tool thanks ... but look like few things are still decrypted ...well m not really sure though ... ex. "ypiaelbtliw" ...